# Is overflow auto in a page applied to HTML or BODY, by default?

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar, overflow, default

In a simple page where there is no overflow property specified, if the content overflows the window scrollbars appear.

Is the `overflow: auto` or `scroll` applied by the browser by default to the HTML or to the BODY element?

Example:

```css
div {
  height: 200vh;
  border: 10px solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 3):

`overflow` is always defaulted to `visible` on every element on which it is not specified.

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.
>
> Using the overflow property with a value different to visible (its
>   default) will create a new block formatting context. This is
>   technically necessary — if a float intersected with the scrolling
>   element it would forcibly rewrap the content. The rewrap would happen
>   after each scroll step, leading to a slow scrolling experience.

`visible` is however, different from `scroll` which enforces scrolling bars, even when no clipping occurs. Visible allows the content to be rendered outside the viewport, and allows scrolling bars to appear whenever content is overflowing the initial viewport.

In your example, `body` is the reason for the scrollbars. Your body's content is rendered outside of the viewport (the `div` inside it). Therefore, it automatically displays scrolling bars, specific to the body- the scrolling bars are being rendered on the `viewport` instead of the element itself.

Example:

```css
html, body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div {
  background-color: #F00;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Quote is from: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: So in the example in which one is it applied? The example displays scrollbars so Im not sure it is *visible* the default value in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Its default value is `overflow:visible;`

The overflow property controls what happens to content that breaks outside of its bounds. here's what you can set it to:

- visible: content is not clipped when it proceeds outside its box.
  This is the default value of the property.
- hidden: overflowing content will be hidden.
- scroll: similar to hidden except users will be able to scroll through
  the hidden content. scroll-bar appear even if no content is there to scroll through.
- auto: if the content proceeds outside its box then that content will
  be hidden whilst a scroll bar should be visible for users to    read
  the rest of the content.
- initial: uses the default value which is visible
- inherit: sets the overflow to the value of its parent element.

Here are some good resources :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflow.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: If the default value is *visible*, then why do scrollbars appear? To which element do those belong?

Comment: they are bound to the body. see in `visible` there is no max-height of element  and if height is more then viewport it adds a scrollbar.